# Тишина - русизм чи питоме слово?

Tags: іменники, росіянізм

Виникла думка, чи тишина - це, випадково, не русизм? Адже у російській мові теж це слово є:

> **[тишина](http://www.endic.ru/kuzhecov/Tishina-72296.html)** -ы́; ж. 1. Отсутствие звуков, говора, шума; безмолвие, молчание. Ночная, абсолютная, глубокая т. Неловкая т. Т. утра. Водворить тишину. Соблюдать, нарушать т. В лесу т. Мёртвая, гробовая т. (усилит.). 2. Душевное спокойствие, умиротворение. В душе мир и т. 3. Отсутствие вражды, ссоры, общественных волнений, беспорядков. Мнимая, общественная т. Т. мира. Установились т. и порядок. В доме мир и т.

Зверталася у СУМ-11, там пише, що:

> **[Тишина](http://sum.in.ua/s/tyshyna)** - Те саме, що тиша.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У словниковій статті [СУМу](http://sum.in.ua/s/tyshyna) бачимо позначку *рідко.*

Отже, вживати в українській мові вживати це слово можна, але з обережністю. На мою думку, пов’язане це з використанням слова **тишина** у сталих словосполученнях ( замість тишина потрібно вживати **тиша**):

> "прервать **тишину**" - "перервати **тишу**" (потрібно "порушувати **тишу**")

[Є. С. РЕГУШЕВСЬКИЙ, М. С. РАЗУМЕЙКО "РОСІЙСЬКО-УКРАЇНСЬКИЙ СЛОВНИК-ДОВІДНИК СТІЙКИХ ДІЄСЛІВНО-ІМЕННИХ СЛОВОСПОЛУЧЕНЬ"](http://abetka.ukrlife.org/dieslova.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Ледь не кожна словянська мова [маїть](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/ti%C5%A1ina) структуру **tixъ* +‎ **-ina*.

Східні

- Білоруська: *цішыня*
- Російська: *тишина́*
- Українська: *тишина́*

Південні

- Ст. церковнословянська: *тишина*
- Болгарська: *тишина́*
- Пн. македонська: *тишина*
- Штокавська: *tišìna*
- Словенська: *tišína*

Західні

- Польська: *ciszyna* (рідкоуживане)
- Сілезська: *ciszyna*

Якщо [ужити](http://uacorpus.org/Kyiv/ua/poshuk-u-grak/grafiki-cql) порівнювальні ґрафіки на основі *General Regionally Annotated Corpus of Ukrainian, Jul. 2023*, то щодо старих джерел, як завжди, складно зробити висновки, але помітно, що десь від 1960 *тишина* остаточно стало марґіналом.

[image: ҐРАК]

Тож саме слово явно не єʼ росіянізмом, але, по сутї, вибуло зі загального ужитку.

Answer (score 0):

Неспотворені російсько-українські словники перекладають "тишина" як "тиша" https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on

Словник Грінченка не дає слова тишина, а всі приклади вжитку в СУМі дано після 1948 року – року видачі горезвісного Російсько-українського словника в москві.

Отже, 100% росіянізм.

Comment: Чим спотворений «Словарь росийсько-український 1893–1898рр.» (М.Уманець, А.Спілка.), що наводить: Тишина́ = ти́ша (С. Л. Ш.), ти́хість, тишина́. С. Ш. — Тиша дивная, таємная всюди міцно залягла. Мова. — Де згода в семействі, де мир і тишина. Кот.

Comment: Так само «Російсько-український словник 1930р.» (О. Ізюмов): 
Тишина, тишь – ти́ша, -ші, тишина́, -ни́.

Comment: Щодо словаря незнаю, а от якщо він і рус-1930 змусили мене засумніватися щодо тишини.